# A question of range.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a,b,c,d,e$ are positive reals, such that $a+b+c+d+e=8$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=16$,then the range of $e$ is?

I dont even know how to proceed with problems like these. I have an idea that $A.M-G.M$ might be helpful. Is it true? If yes, then how to go about it?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789371/max-of-e-with-abcde-8-and-a2b2c2d2e2-16. – Both found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%2Bd%5E2%2Be%5E2%3D16%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cauchy inequality:

$$ 16-e^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\geq {1\over 4}(a+b+c+d)^2 ={1\over 4} (8-e)^2$$

So we have $$5e^2-16e\leq 0\Longrightarrow e\in (0,{16\over 5}] $$

Comment: what exactly is the cauchy inequality? any other methods other than cauchy inequality?

Comment: Quadratic mean - arithmetic mean

Comment: what is a quadratic mean?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadratic_mean

Comment: $$Q.M. \geq A.M. $$

Comment: @JohnWatson: I think zero should be excluded

Comment: @Vasya why should zero be excluded?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar: $e$ is supposed to be a positive real, right?

Comment: @Vasya ok so since zero isnt a positive real it should be excluded right?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar: that's right